# What happens when opponent draws Exodia and Deck Out in the same turn?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I've dueled with an opponent that had an Exodia deck draw-based. It happens that he managed to draw Exodia, but in the same time that he decked out. Which win condition has priority? Exodia "effect" or deck out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deck out is irrelevant. The player drawing Exodia (and presumably completing the set in hand) has already won the duel.

Even if the player has not completed Exodia in hand, they do not lose until they are **required to draw *and* are unable to draw**. They may sit with an empty deck until next draw phase if there is nothing else to cause the duel to end.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it included a link to the rules, say: http://www.yugioh-card.com/uk/rulebook/Rulebook_v9_en.pdf with page number of the rule (page 28).

Comment: The rule book doesn't explain the priority of endgame conditions, nor is it unambiguous (it says "unable to draw a card" which is a much looser condition than "unable to draw and required to draw, at the same time" there are situations where the loose condition ends the game but the tighter one would not). I think it causes greater confusion by adding the rulebook than leaving it out. @Mosquite

Comment: My thought was that having a source for your answer would be better than just saying "this is the way it is".

Comment: I understand the thought and appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately as an authoritative source, it doesn't support the answer in a meaningful or useful way, as mentioned. @Mosquite

Comment: Correct. Worth noticing that the draw is any kind, not just during draw phase. At any moment you cant draw you lose

Comment: So what happens when you're required to draw 2 cards, only have one left and that one completes your Exodia? That would make you lose, right?

Comment: @DonFusili In that case, such effect that says "draw 2 cards" **cannot be activated**, because it does not meet the requirement of having at least 2 cards to draw. If you only have one card left, it can only be drawn if an effects says "draw 1 card"

Comment: @DonFusili also say for example you had a hand destruction in hand (both players discard 2 then draw 2) and your opponent only had 1 card in deck, hand destruction would not be able to be activated

Comment: @Nij official rulings are that whatever card effect triggered the draw must resolve fully (e.g. for Graceful Charity, the player that just drew the last piece of Exodia must first discard 2 cards). In the case of a draw effect that would cause Deck-Out (e.g. Pot of Greed with Exodia being the only card left in the deck), the Deck-Out occurs during the resolution of that effect and Exodia's win condition never gets checked for.

Comment: POG can resolve and attempt to draw from a deck that only has 1 card left in it. Same for Appropriate (draw 2 cards when your opponent draws a card outside their draw phase). There are explicit rulings covering what happens if that single card is Exodia, and they specifically state that Exodia doesn't activate because the game already ended by Deck-Out before Exodia's win condition would be checked for.